# Amazon SageMaker kMeans won't take sparse matrix (csr_matrix) as input, any alternatives before using a dense matrix?

Tags: sparse-matrix, k-means, amazon-sagemaker

I want to apply sagemaker's kMeans algorithm to a sparse matrix, obtained with `TfidfVectorizer` from `sklearn`'s library.

Ideally I would like to provide the input data to Sagemaker's kMeans implementation as sparse matrix `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, but when I this (`kmeans.fit(kmeans.record_set(train_data))`) I get the following error:

`TypeError: must be real number, not csr_matrix`

Of course, if I pass a dense matrix the algorithm will work (`train_data.toarray()`) but the amount of memory it would need is ginormous. Any possible alternatives before I incur into using supersized amazon instances?

Comment: The documentation page shows that it supports RecordIO as input. So maybe [my answer here can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075964/3374996)

Comment: thanks @VivekKumar! Indeed your answer pointed me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was in the SageMaker python SDK. There you can find a function that transforms a scipy sparse matrix to a sparse tensor (`write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor`).

The complete code that solved the problem without having to incur into a dense matrix is the following:

```
from sagemaker.amazon.common import write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform('your_train_data') # output: sparse scipy matrix
sagemaker_bucket = 'your-bucket' 
data_key = 'kmeans_lowlevel/data'
data_location = f"s3://{sagemaker_bucket}/{data_key}"
buf = io.BytesIO()
write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor(buf, tfidf_matrix)
buf.seek(0)
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(sagemaker_bucket).Object(data_key).upload_fileobj(buf)
```

After doing this, in the `create_training_params` configuration you'll have to feed the S3Uri field with the data location you have provided to store the sparse matrix in S3:

```
create_training_params = \
{
    ... # all other params

    "InputDataConfig": [
        {
            "ChannelName": "train",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                    "S3Uri": data_location, # YOUR_DATA_LOCATION_GOES_HERE
                    "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated"
                }
            },
            "CompressionType": "None",
            "RecordWrapperType": "None"
        }
    ]
}
```